# trash before body of http request and after

Tags: c++, https

on some sites to https body adding trash before and after. I don't know what is this.
most of the sites work fine. maybe the problem is in the https?
what is b7 and 0 ? why?

Request:

```
GET /api/3/ticker/ltc_btc? HTTP/1.1
Host: yobit.net
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 22:34:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d1d616fde8dba864f15748d871ff9819f1564180481; expires=Sat, 25-Jul-20 22:34:41 GMT; path=/; domain=.yobit.net; HttpOnly; Secure
    Set-Cookie: locale=en; expires=Thu, 26-Jul-2029 22:34:41 GMT; path=/
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block;
    x-download-options: noopen
    Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
    Server: cloudflare
    CF-RAY: 4fc9d7a81c548ff7-DME

    b7
    {"ltc_btc":{"high":0.00964924,"low":0.00935811,"avg":0.00950367,"vol":192.35202559,"vol_cur":20190.08465994,"last":0.00964229,"buy":0.00957471,"sell":0.00964486,"updated":1564180338}}
    0
```

```
Response sendHTTPS(Request& request) {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData)) {
            return Response();
        }
        std::string req = str(request);
        addrinfo* pAddrInfo;
        getaddrinfo(request.uri.host().c_str(), "443", 0, &pAddrInfo);

        SOCKET connection = socket(
            pAddrInfo->ai_family,
            pAddrInfo->ai_socktype,
            pAddrInfo->ai_protocol
        );
        if (!connection)
            return Response();

        int error = connect(connection, pAddrInfo->ai_addr, pAddrInfo->ai_addrlen);
        if (error)
            return Response();

        SSL_library_init();
        SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
        SSL_load_error_strings();

        const SSL_METHOD *meth = TLSv1_2_client_method();
        SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);

        SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        if (!ssl)
            return Response();

        int sock = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, connection);

        error = SSL_connect(ssl);
        if (error <= 0)
            return Response();

        int len = SSL_write(ssl, req.c_str(), req.size());
        if (len <= 0)
            return Response();

        std::string result = "";
        char buffer[16384] = { 0 };//16 kib
        int bytes_recv = 0;

        do {
            bytes_recv = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (bytes_recv > 0)
                result.append(buffer, bytes_recv);
        } while (bytes_recv > 0);

        closesocket(connection);
        SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        SSL_free(ssl);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

        return Response(result);
    }
```

Comment: Please try to edit your question. It is unclear what you're asking or when this happens. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This is not "trash", but a fundamental part of HTTP 1.1. This is chunked content transfer encoding, see [section 3.6.1 of RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). This is specified by the presence of the

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

in the response's headers. If the response contains such a header you will need to decode the contents of the response using chunked transfer encoding. This is not very complicated, see RFC 2616 for complete details.

Alternatively, you may specify `HTTP/1.0` in your original request, to indicate to the server that your hand-written HTTP client does not support protocol level 1.1. HTTP 1.0 does not have chunked transfer encoding and there's no need to deal with it.

However if your application requires some other HTTP 1.1 feature, you have no choice but prepare to deal with chunked transfer encoding in any response from the server. Your client has no means to indicate whether it accepts chunked transfer encoding to the server. Whether to send chunks or not is entirely up to the server.